# Shorter way to write Jquery If Statement with multiple options for the "IF"

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Is there an easier / shorter way with Jquery for writing an if statement like this:

```
if(number === "0" ) { degrees = "-160"; }
if(number === "1" ) { degrees = "-158"; }
if(number === "2" ) { degrees = "-156"; }
if(number === "3" ) { degrees = "-154"; }
if(number === "4" ) { degrees = "-152"; }
if(number === "5" ) { degrees = "-150"; }
if(number === "6" ) { degrees = "-148"; }
if(number === "7" ) { degrees = "-146"; }
if(number === "8" ) { degrees = "-144"; }
if(number === "9" ) { degrees = "-142"; }
if(number === "10") { degrees = "-140"; }
```

The number variable is just an input field where the user enters a number from 0 - 10.

Thank you!

Comment: If it's a finite list, I'd suggest limiting it to those choices. For example: `<select><option value="{value}">0<option><option value="-160">n+1<option></select>`

Comment: Go to your favorite search engine, and search for *lookup table*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your specific problem you can just write a function as bellow

```
var getDegrees = function(number){
   return -160 + ((+number)*2);
}
```

and call it like bellow

```
getDegrees("1") // will return -158
getDegrees("10") // will return -140
getDegrees(10) // will also return -158
```

Comment: you don't need to convert into number using + operator. JavaScript does it automatically "2"*2 == 4.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal thanx for your reply. I didn't know that. And "2" + 2 gives "22". So that's one reason I don't want to take risk

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly. I changed it slightly to fit my code, but the core worked great.

Comment: @Mritunjay There's no risk. Everything is clearly specified [in the specification (§12.6.3)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-multiplicative-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) such that both side will be casted into a Number if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Um... Quick and easy with an array.

```
degrees = [-160, -158, ..., -140][number];
```

Or, to avoid hard-coding values into the code, try to create a function which yields the value based on a formula.

```
degress = -160 + 2 * number;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array instead of the `if`s.

```
var degrees = ["-160","-158","-156","-154","-152","-150","-148","-146","-144","-142","-140"];
```

And then you can simply output the correct degrees with

```
console.log(degrees[number]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `swich`

```
switch(number ) { 
case "0":degrees = "-160"; 
       break;
case "1" : degrees = "-158"; 
       break;
...
...

case "10" : degrees = "-140";
     break;
}
```

Comment: longer than if statement though.

Comment: `switch..case` is slow.

Comment: A lot of redundancy I must say, which is usually a bad thing to have.

Answer (score 0):

a switch statement might work for you

```
switch(number){
    case 1:
       doThis();
       break;
    case 2:
       doThat();
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var num=-160;
    if(number >= "0" and number <= "10" ){
        degree = num+ (number *2); // diff is 2
    }
```

or you can use simple one line

```
 degree = -160 + (number * 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map as created below and retrive values using `number` variable

```
var map = new Object();
map["0"]="-160";
map["1"]="-158"; 
map["2"]="-156"; 
map["3"]="-154"; 
map["4"]="-152"; 
map["5"]="-150"; 
map["6"]="-148"; 
map["7"]="-146"; 
map["8"]="-144"; 
map["9"]="-142";
map["10"]="-140";
```

and retrive values like

```
degrees = map[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, i'm like use like this :

```
var obj = {
   0 : '-160',
   1 : '-158'
}

if ( $.inArray(number, [1,2,3,...10] ) !== -1 ) {
   degree = obj[number];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use switch-case block?

```
switch (number) {
    case "0":
        degrees = "-160";
    case "1":
        degrees = "-158";
        .
        .
        .
    default:
    }
```

However you can convert number to int. then you simply write only this command:

```
degrees = "-" + 160 - number * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object instead, like this:

```
 var myObject = {'0':'-160', '1':'-158', '2':'-156'};

 var degrees = myObject[number];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object having properties `0` - `10` , set `degrees` as value of property within object

```js
var obj = {
  "0": "-160",
  "1": "-158",
  "2": "-156",
  "3": "-154",
  "4": "-152",
  "5": "-150",
  "6": "-148",
  "7": "-146",
  "8": "-144",
  "9": "-142",
  "10": "-140"
};

// set pseudo-random number
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

// set `degrees` 
var degrees = obj[number];

document.body.textContent = degrees;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
degrees = ( -160 + 2 * number ).toString();
```

```js
var number = "3";
var degrees = ( -160 + 2 * number ).toString();

console.log( number, degrees );
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a few ways I could answer this. It's not exactly *shorter*, but your intentions may be more apparent and direct with a `switch` rather than `if`s:

```
switch (number)
{
    case "0":
        degrees = "-160";
        break;
    case "1":
        degrees = "-158";
        break;
    ...
}
```

But, for this type of thing, a lookup table may be more clear and concise:

```
var degreesLookupTable = {
    "0": "-160",
    "1": "-158",
    "2": "-156",
    "3": "-154",
    "4": "-152",
    "5": "-150",
    "6": "-148",
    "7": "-146",
    "8": "-144",
    "9": "-142",
    "10": "-140"
};

if (number in degreesLookupTable)
    degrees = degreesLookupTable[number]
else
    throw "Number not found in degree map!"
```

See the Lookup Tables section, [here](http://www.jayway.com/2013/04/07/javascript-conditionals/), for more information.

Thirdly, there seems to be a direct mathematical relationship between `number` and `degrees`. Maybe just write a function to calculate `degrees` directly based on the value of `number`?